# Toggle Button not toggling

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-8

I've got a Toggle Button in WPF, however on pressing it, it does not seem to remain pressed in. It is simply acting like a normal button. Could this possibly be an issue with Windows 8? I basically mouse over the button, click it - the button is pressed, and pops right out again. This is the simple code I've used:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnJoinMode" Grid.Column="5" Click="btnJoinMode_Click" Background="LightGray" Width="28" Padding="2"/>


private void btnJoinMode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnJoinMode.IsChecked == true)
            {
                parentVisualQueryBuilder.HighlightTables(this, true);
            }
            else
            {
                parentVisualQueryBuilder.HighlightTables(this, false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried a binding of its IsChecked property?

Comment: All I've got is that code. Haven't modified anything at all

Comment: post the code of the event handler `btnJoinMode_Click`.

Comment: ok than try to bind the IsChecked property 
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnJoinMode" Grid.Column="5" Click="btnJoinMode_Click" IsChecked="{Binding YourViewModelProperty}" Background="LightGray" Width="28" Padding="2"/>

Comment: @HighCore - I've tried removing the click event too. Problem persists, so it has nothing to do with the event

Comment: Don't say that it could be anything , please post it anyway

Comment: The code doesn't do anything special, just calls another object's method. As I said, even when I removed the event completely, the problem still persisted

Comment: Isolate the cause. Create a new WPF project. Add ToggleButton. See if it toggles.

Comment: Please post your whole XAML.
And you said that you use the MVVM but why you still write code behind and Bindings?

Comment: MVVM isn't about getting rid of the code-behind.

Comment: Little update everyone - I started a new project with just a single Toggle Button, and sure enough it didn't work there either. I suspect this has something to do with Windows 8

Comment: @narohi but its most likely to avoid code behind, so if not for what does commands still make sense?

Comment: Same problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450751/togglebutton-doesnt-show-any-state

Comment: You could add your discoveries as an answer to this question. Hopefully someone else with Windows 8 can verify. @Venson You're right, there isn't very much code-behind in an MVVM app. I only wanted to point out that this isn't the purpose of the pattern.

Comment: I can confirm that. I test it with one of my DevExpress apps it looks very different if its checked, but if i set a WPF toggle button near to that with the same Property binding it seems like nothing happens to that normal button so its just a Style "issue" @narohi i need to confess that i write code behind in my WPF apps too but i thought that this kind of event is not in point of the MVVM. So at the end we got the same point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually appears to be a known issue. I found [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763597/togglebutton-doesnt-show-any-state) bug resolution page and Microsoft have confirmed that a fix should be out shortly.

Comment: They said on Jan 31 2013 that "A fix will appear in a forthcoming compatibility update". It doesn't seem that that ever happened.